# Create EC2 instance without starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I would like to create some EC2 instance, but before it starts do some stuff using instance ID generated for this instance. Is there any option in `aws ec2 run-instances` or another `aws ec2` command for creating an AWS EC2 instance without starting it? A workaround would be generating UUID to tag this instance and associate this UUID instead of instance ID, or stopping just after run instance, but I would prefer some smarter solution.

Comment: What do you mean by by "do some stuff"? The right way to act on the instance before it is fully operational is to give the instance some [userdata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). If you really want your instance to remain shutdown and start with the right datas, you can prepare an `EBS` volume on another instance and attach it to the one booting but I would not recommend that, userdatas is the way to go.

Comment: @iMil by "do some stuff" I mean create some resources which will be used by the instance. I can set them up if they do not exist in `/etc/rc.local`, but I this makes more conditional code. I know how user data works, but I can't see how it could help me with doing some action on instance starts existing event but before it starts working. I want to be able to reset an instance and don't create the resources again.

Comment: Actually what you're trying to do is exactly what userdatas are for, they are executed way before `rc.local` and in fact before your Linux system enters the multi-user stage. Another option would be to create an AMI (for example using [packer](https://www.packer.io/)) that would setup what you need to at the instance creation. And btw, packer do start an instance in order to build the AMI :)

Comment: @iMil: I just paid attention to the part of user-data docs telling about running with instance launch, tried your suggestion and it solved my actual issue. why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Great! will do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as I was telling to @pt12lol in the comments, this is exactly what [userdata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is for.

From Amazon's documentation:

*When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common automated configuration tasks and even run scripts after the instance starts. You can pass two types of user data to Amazon EC2: shell scripts and cloud-init directives. You can also pass this data into the launch wizard as plain text, as a file (this is useful for launching instances via the command line tools), or as base64-encoded text (for API calls).*

User-datas can be passed to the instance at creation time, for instance using the `--user-data` flag in the `aws` cli or the Userdata text box in AWS console.

Comment: This is most applicable solution for the question. 
_

Answer (score 5):

There is no option under EC2 to create an instance without starting it. Once you create an instance it will automatically will move from pending to running state

Docs -
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html